# Laravel post request api is not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, post, postman

I am using bluehost shared hosting and my API is not working.

Whenever I hit the api url through postman, it shows me an error about enabling javascript. It says

> For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript in your web browser.

The same code is working fine in godaddy.

I talked with bluehost support team. They are telling me that the basic javascript is already enabled. Then the problem is coming from where? Is there any thing I need to change in laravel?

Comment: That sounds like it's not Laravel who is answering your requests. Check endpoints url, and try adding the heders: ` Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json ` . Can you load the application vía web correctly? Is possible than requests are not been redirected correctly to Laravel due to the home path of the site? For example if its not accesing to the public folder but another in place.

Answer (score -1):

@Shah Postman don't allow Javascript to run in preview mode for security reasons.

Source : https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3344#issuecomment-320249284